# Why does this query work?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

sails.js uses waterline and there is a nice [documentation](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline#query-methods).

```
User.findOne()
.where({ id: 2 })
.then(function(user){
    var comments = Comment.find({userId: user.id}).then(function(comments){
        return comments;
```

if i leave out `"id: 2"` and use just find() instead of `findOne()` the query still works, but why? `find()` should return a list so I shouldn't be able to just say user.id in the subquery

how can I access `Comment.find({userId: user.id})` if I didn't receive one single record but a list of users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oh ok, I just found the answer

that `Comment.find({userId: user.id})` in fact doesn't make sense but it does not make the query fail but is the same as if i would have put

```
Comment.find({userId: null})
```

the result is the same, 
the query will run as if there were no search parameter/filter.